# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited (run_in_executor )

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to write an async function for my program, but faced this problem: **RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Generator.generate_token' was never awaited**

Myc code:

```
    @classmethod
    async def generate_token(cls, iter: int, combination: dict) -> List[dict]:
        first_layer = Image.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, list(combination.values())[0]))
        attributes = []

        async for layer, attribute in list(combination.items())[1:]:
            result = await cls.paste_image(first_layer, Image.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, attribute)).convert('RGBA'))
            await attributes.append({'trait_type': layer, 'value': attribute})

        await result.convert('RGB').save(os.path.join('output/', f'{iter}.jpg'), 'JPEG', optimize=True)

    return attributes

    @classmethod
    async def generate_tokens(cls, loop, combinations: List[dict], collection: dict) -> dict:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()*4) as executor:
            for iter, combination in enumerate(combinations, 1):
                await loop.run_in_executor(executor, cls.generate_token, iter, combination)

            return {'success': True, 'message': 'Generation completed'}

    @classmethod
    def generate_combinations(cls, traits: dict, id: int) -> dict:
        # above i just get the data i will pass

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(cls.generate_tokens(loop, completed_combinations, collection))
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Please share what part of your code is actually causing the error, because that isn't in the piece you've provided. Somewhere, you call `generate_token()` without await

Comment: Why are you trying to run `generate_token` in an executor? You should just use `asyncio.gather`. You can also replace most of the code in `generate_combinations` with `asyncio.run`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.